# XSD to Jaxb does not generate package-info.java

Tags: maven-2, xsd, jaxb2

I have this sample XSD - I am trying to generate Java classess using Jaxb. Java classes are getting generated but we do not see package-info.java class getting generated, because the package-info.java is not getting generated marshalling fails with QName error. Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified"> 
      <xs:element name="Parent">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="testuser"/>
            <xs:element ref="testpassword"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="testname"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="testuser">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="myname" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="testpassword">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="mytestpassword" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="testname">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="mytestname" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
```

My POM.xml:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <extension>true</extension>
          <args>
            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
            </args>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
              <version>0.6.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
              <version>0.6.0</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
          <bindingIncludes>
            <include>sample/test_binding.xml</include>
          </bindingIncludes>
          <schemaIncludes>
            <include>sample.xsd</include>
          </schemaIncludes>
             <generatePackage>com.test</generatePackage>
        </configuration>
      </plugin> 
  </plugins>
```

binding file entry:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:a="http://abc.dev.java.net">
</bindings>
```

Comment: Can you show the command (or maybe .pom file section) by which you're generating the java classes?. Usually the option `npa` is used to suppress the generation of package-info file. If it is set to true, you just need to remove it.

Comment: I attached the pom targets